# RegExp matching url but not url with a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match specific types of url's in javascript. If that url is a match I need make sure the url does not include a specific word. I want to match urls *without* the word collection.

I have tried to create a negative lookahead but it is not working. I can get it to work for a single word but not in the middle of my search.  I am still getting the hang of the negative lookahead so I am sure I am messing it up.

Example:

```
http://m.store.com/shop/product/thing-that-has-collection?ID=234&CatID=456 - do not match.
http://m.store.com/shop/product/thing-that-is-something-else?ID=432&CatID=654 - match.
```

Here is my regExp to match all the urls.

```
\/shop\/product\/[\w-]*
```

My attempt at hacking a negative lookahead. I know this does not work and I have tried variations of this. I am guessing I am going about this all wrong but I am trying.

```
(?!-collection\?)\/shop\/product\/[\w-]*
(?<!-collection\?)\/shop\/product\/[\w-]*
\/shop\/product\/[\w-]*(?<!-collection\?)
```

Many thanks

Comment: JavaScript regex don't have lookbehinds.

Comment: You're almost there. Just add `.*` inside the negative lookahead `(?!.*?-collection\?)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!.*?\bcollection\b)\/shop\/product\/[\w-]*
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/2